# ClickOnce error: Manifest identity has one or more invalid characters

Tags: .net, clickonce, manifest

I am trying to deploy a .NET 3.5 application using a third-party assembly.  I can create the ClickOnce setup program with no problems. When I try to run setup, however, I get this message:

> Cannot Start Application: Cannot continue. The application is improperly formatted. Contact the application vendor for assistance.

Here is the important part of the error log:

```
ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of <my application path>.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Exception reading manifest from file <my application path>.exe.manifest: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        + Application manifest is not semantically valid.
        + Manifest identity has one or more invalid characters: ABISFoundationSDK_C#.
```

As you can see, the SDK identity name has a pound (#) sign in it. Is there a way that I can change the identity of the SDK assembly to remove the pound sign? It is unlikely that the third-party provider will make this change to the assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you add the dll to the deployment? Did you just add it and edit the manifest?

The best way to include a 3rd party assembly with your deployment is this:

Add the assembly to your project. Set the build action to 'none' and set "copy to output directory" to "do not copy". Then delete the reference you have to that assembly. Re-add the reference and point to that local copy in your project; set "copy local" to "true" on the reference properties.

If you don't have a direct reference to the assembly in your project, add it to your project and set the build action to "content" and "copy to output directory" to "copy always".

If it is the octothorpe that is really causing your problem, can you rename it? Does it actually have the # in the name of the assembly?

Comment: I tried your recommendation but I still get the error about the octothorpe in the manifest.  Even if I rename the dll, the octothorpe is somewhere inside the file (in the Identity field?) causing the problem.  Thanks for your help, though.